# IBM MQ Create Context throws com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException "Channel not defined remotely" (RC 2540)

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

While trying to create the context, this code throws the exception below:

```
package com.mycompany.mq.client;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.jms.JMSConsumer;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.JMSProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;
import com.prowidesoftware.swift.io.RJEReader;
import com.prowidesoftware.swift.model.SwiftMessage;

public class FileScanner {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("RJEFileParser");

    @Test
    public void testPublish() throws Exception {

        int count=0;

        long m1,m2;

        // Create a connection factory
        JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
        JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();
        // Set the properties
        String s;
        s=Config.get("HOST"); // 10.32.1.69
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, s);
        s=Config.get("PORT"); // 1414
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT,  Integer.parseInt(s));
        s=Config.get("CHANNEL"); // MQCLI.CLNTCONN
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL,  s);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        s=Config.get("QMGR"); // RJE_PerfTest
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, s);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "mq-cli");
        cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
        s=Config.get("APP_USER"); // app
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, s);
        s=Config.get("APP_PASSWORD"); // password
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, s);

        // Create JMS objects

        try {

            JMSContext context = cf.createContext(); // Throws exception
        ...    
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

The exception thrown:

> com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSRuntimeException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed
>   to connect to queue manager 'RJE_PerfTest' with connection mode
>   'Client' and host name '10.32.1.69(1414)'. Check the queue manager is
>   started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener
>   running. Please see the linked exception for more information.    at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException.getUnchecked(DetailedJMSException.java:267)
>     at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.convertJMSException(JmsErrorUtils.java:173)
>     at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createContext(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:478)
>     at
>   com.mycompany.mq.client.FileScanner.testPublish(FileScanner.java:61)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
>   Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with
>   compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2540'
>   ('MQRC_UNKNOWN_CHANNEL_NAME').    at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
>     at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.(WMQConnection.java:424)
>     at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8475)
>     at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7815)
>     at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303)
>     at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createContext(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:444)
>     ... 24 more Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException:
>   CC=2;RC=2540;AMQ9204: Connection to host '10.32.1.69(1414)' rejected.
>   [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2540;AMQ9520: Channel not
>   defined remotely.
>   [3=MQCLI.CLNTCONN]],3=10.32.1.69(1414),5=RemoteConnection.analyseErrorSegment]
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2314)
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1285)
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:377)
>     at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:562)    at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.(WMQConnection.java:357)
>     ... 28 more Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException:
>   CC=2;RC=2540;AMQ9520: Channel not defined remotely. [3=MQCLI.CLNTCONN]
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.analyseErrorSegment(RemoteConnection.java:4464)
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.receiveTSH(RemoteConnection.java:3199)
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.initSess(RemoteConnection.java:1274)
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:895)
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:416)
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:312)
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:146)
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1761)
>     ... 32 more

```
DIS CHANNEL ('MQCLI.CLNTCONN')
     3 : DIS CHANNEL ('MQCLI.CLNTCONN')
AMQ8414: Display Channel details.
   CHANNEL(MQCLI.CLNTCONN)                 CHLTYPE(CLNTCONN)
   AFFINITY(PREFERRED)                     ALTDATE(2020-03-06)
   ALTTIME(11.34.36)                       CERTLABL( )
   CLNTWGHT(0)                             COMPHDR(NONE)
   COMPMSG(NONE)                           CONNAME(10.32.1.69)
   DEFRECON(NO)                            DESCR( )
   HBINT(300)                              KAINT(AUTO)
   LOCLADDR( )                             MAXMSGL(4194304)
   MODENAME( )                             PASSWORD( )
   QMNAME(RJE_PerfTest)                    RCVDATA( )
   RCVEXIT( )                              SCYDATA( )
   SCYEXIT( )                              SENDDATA( )
   SENDEXIT( )                             SHARECNV(10)
   SSLCIPH( )                              SSLPEER( )
   TPNAME( )                               TRPTYPE(TCP)
   USERID( )
```

With the Queue Manager configured as

```
DIS QMGR
     2 : DIS QMGR
AMQ8408: Display Queue Manager details.
   QMNAME(RJE_PerfTest)                    ACCTCONO(DISABLED)
   ACCTINT(1800)                           ACCTMQI(OFF)
   ACCTQ(OFF)                              ACTIVREC(MSG)
   ACTVCONO(DISABLED)                      ACTVTRC(OFF)
   ALTDATE(2020-03-04)                     ALTTIME(15.48.24)
   AUTHOREV(DISABLED)                      CCSID(437)
   CERTLABL(ibmwebspheremqrje_perftest)    CERTVPOL(ANY)
   CHAD(DISABLED)                          CHADEV(DISABLED)
   CHADEXIT( )                             CHLEV(DISABLED)
   CHLAUTH(ENABLED)                        CLWLDATA( )
   CLWLEXIT( )                             CLWLLEN(100)
   CLWLMRUC(999999999)                     CLWLUSEQ(LOCAL)
   CMDEV(DISABLED)                         CMDLEVEL(800)
   COMMANDQ(SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE)    CONFIGEV(DISABLED)
   CONNAUTH(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)
   CRDATE(2020-02-20)                      CRTIME(16.25.00)
   CUSTOM( )                               DEADQ( )
   DEFCLXQ(SCTQ)                           DEFXMITQ( )
   DESCR( )                                DISTL(YES)
   INHIBTEV(DISABLED)                      IPADDRV(IPV4)
   LOCALEV(DISABLED)                       LOGGEREV(DISABLED)
   MARKINT(5000)                           MAXHANDS(256)
   MAXMSGL(104857600)                      MAXPROPL(NOLIMIT)
   MAXPRTY(9)                              MAXUMSGS(10000)
   MONACLS(QMGR)                           MONCHL(OFF)
   MONQ(OFF)                               PARENT( )
   PERFMEV(DISABLED)                       PLATFORM(WINDOWSNT)
   PSMODE(ENABLED)                         PSCLUS(ENABLED)
   PSNPMSG(DISCARD)                        PSNPRES(NORMAL)
   PSRTYCNT(5)                             PSSYNCPT(IFPER)
   QMID(RJE_PerfTest_2020-02-20_16.25.00)
   REMOTEEV(DISABLED)                      REPOS( )
   REPOSNL( )                              REVDNS(ENABLED)
   ROUTEREC(MSG)                           SCHINIT(QMGR)
   SCMDSERV(QMGR)                          SPLCAP(DISABLED)
   SSLCRLNL( )                             SSLCRYP( )
   SSLEV(DISABLED)                         SSLFIPS(NO)
   SSLKEYR(C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\RJE_PerfTest\ssl\key)
   SSLRKEYC(0)                             STATACLS(QMGR)
   STATCHL(OFF)                            STATINT(1800)
   STATMQI(OFF)                            STATQ(OFF)
   STRSTPEV(ENABLED)                       SUITEB(NONE)
   SYNCPT                                  TREELIFE(1800)
   TRIGINT(999999999)                      VERSION(08000005)
   XRCAP(NO)
```

The connectivity works fine.

How to troubleshoot this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes out of a basic confusion between the channel types.

The client connection channel configured in the server is for something else, as pointed out in this forum: https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=248122

> "When you say you created a 'Client Connection' on the Queue Manager,
>   do you mean you created a channel with type CLNTCONN? This needs to be
>   type SVRCONN to allow client connections. CLNTCONN channels are never
>   use dby QMgrs - they are only there to create Channel Tables for
>   clients."

The client connection requires a server connection channel, created as explained here>

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031730_.htm

```
DEFINE CHANNEL(SWFMQ.CHANNEL) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) TRPTYPE(TCP)
     7 : DEFINE CHANNEL(SWFMQ.CHANNEL) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) TRPTYPE(TCP)
AMQ8014: WebSphere MQ channel created.
```

Now my channel looks:

```
DIS CHANNEL ('SWFMQ.CHANNEL')
     8 : DIS CHANNEL ('SWFMQ.CHANNEL')
AMQ8414: Display Channel details.
   CHANNEL(SWFMQ.CHANNEL)                  CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
   ALTDATE(2020-03-06)                     ALTTIME(13.09.41)
   CERTLABL( )                             COMPHDR(NONE)
   COMPMSG(NONE)                           DESCR( )
   DISCINT(0)                              HBINT(300)
   KAINT(AUTO)                             MAXINST(999999999)
   MAXINSTC(999999999)                     MAXMSGL(4194304)
   MCAUSER( )                              MONCHL(QMGR)
   RCVDATA( )                              RCVEXIT( )
   SCYDATA( )                              SCYEXIT( )
   SENDDATA( )                             SENDEXIT( )
   SHARECNV(10)                            SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)
   SSLCIPH( )                              SSLPEER( )
   TRPTYPE(TCP)
```